# Difficulties to establish a ppp connection to a GSM provider

Tags: modem, ppp, mobile, chat-command

I want to establish a `ppp` link to a GSM provider with my cell phone modem. The modem gets recognized and I can send AT commands just fine, but I can not get the connection established.

My `chat` script looks like:

```
#######################################
SAY 'Setting the abort string\n'
SAY '\n'
# Abort String ------------------------------
ABORT 'NO DIAL TONE' ABORT 'NO ANSWER' ABORT 'NO CARRIER' ABORT DELAYED

#######################################
SAY 'Initializing modem\n'
# Modem Initialization
'' AT
OK ATZ

#######################################
SAY '\n'
SAY     'Setting APN\n'
# Access Point Name (APN)
# Incorrect APN or CGDCONT can often cause errors in connection.
# Below are a bunch of different popular APNs

#REG:\s1 AT+cgdcont=1,"IP","proxy"
#OK     'AT+CGDCONT=0,"IP","proxy"'
#OK     'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","proxy"'
#OK     'AT+CGDCONT=2,"IP","proxy"'
OK     'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"'
#OK     'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","ISP.TELUS.COM"'
#OK     'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","INTERNET.COM"'
#OK     'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","ISP.CINGULAR"'
#OK     'AT+CGDCONT=2,"IP","ISP.CINGULAR"'
   ""
```

And in `/var/log/messages` I get the following messages:

```
Jan 11 04:08:49 ariag25 pppd[2518]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Jan 11 04:08:50 ariag25 chat[2520]: abort on (NO DIAL TONE)
Jan 11 04:08:50 ariag25 chat[2520]: abort on (NO ANSWER)
Jan 11 04:08:50 ariag25 chat[2520]: abort on (NO CARRIER)
Jan 11 04:08:50 ariag25 chat[2520]: abort on (DELAYED)
Jan 11 04:08:50 ariag25 chat[2520]: send (AT^M)
Jan 11 04:08:50 ariag25 chat[2520]: expect (OK)
Jan 11 04:08:50 ariag25 chat[2520]: AT^M^M
Jan 11 04:08:50 ariag25 chat[2520]: OK
Jan 11 04:08:50 ariag25 chat[2520]:  -- got it
Jan 11 04:08:50 ariag25 chat[2520]: send (ATZ^M)
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: expect (OK)
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: ^M
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: ATZ^M^M
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: OK
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]:  -- got it
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: send (AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"^M)
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: expect (OK)
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: ^M
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","m2mstatic.apn"^M^M
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: OK
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]:  -- got it
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: send (ATDT*99#^M)
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: expect (CONNECT)
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: ^M
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: ATDT*99#^M^M
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: CONNECT
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]:  -- got it
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 chat[2520]: send (^M)
Jan 11 04:08:51 ariag25 pppd[2518]: Serial connection established.
```

#### Edit

I don't think things are wrong with my chat script but my modem instead. Notice that on the bottom of the messages, the context switched from `chat` to `pppd` - why is that? May my power supply be too weak? That's what I suspect now. Any ideas?

Also, if I do a `killall pppd` after this and try to connect with screen

```
screen /dev/modem 9600
```

the modem doesn't reply anymore until I power cycle it.

However, I'm surprised! I hooked it up to a 2.1A USB power supply.

#### Edit2

My `/etc/ppp/options` looks like:

```
debug
/dev/ttyUSB1
9600
modem
crtscts
lock
connect /etc/ppp/net-connect
asyncmap 0
defaultroute
```

and `/etc/ppp/peers/provider` like this:

```
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/pap -T *99***1#"

# Serial device to which the modem is connected.
/dev/modem

# Speed of the serial line.
9600

# Assumes that your IP address is allocated dynamically by the ISP.
noipdefault
# Try to get the name server addresses from the ISP.
usepeerdns
# Use this connection as the default route.
defaultroute

# Makes pppd "dial again" when the connection is lost.
persist

# Do not ask the remote to authenticate.
noauth
```

Comment: Stuck with the same kind of problem. In my case, `pppd` doesn't establish the network interface. Try `dhclient ppp0`.

Comment: What is your pppd configuration?

Comment: I don't think that's an issue with pppd showing up in your logs. Rather `chat` has done its job and is handing off control to `pppd` to get an IP address. I'd look to your `pppd` setup. It's probably getting hung up, and needs to be configured so that it can get an IP and set up your network connection properly.

Comment: This guide might be of some help in working through your pppd issues: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2109

Comment: @yegorich please see my ppp config above under **edit2**

Comment: May I suggest a strace of the pppd? I think there is some incompatibility/permission problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the "defaultroute" line and it should work.

You can set the route manually if you have to, but you probably don't have to. It looks like you have a script hooked already that sets he routes when a new interface comes up and it's clobbering pppd.

Answer (score 1):

Something is misconfigured with your `pppd` setup. If things are working correctly you should see messages from `pppd` in your logs similar to this:

```
Oct  5 12:37:35 localhost pppd[1289]: Serial connection established.
Oct  5 12:37:35 localhost pppd[1289]: Using interface ppp0
Oct  5 12:37:35 localhost pppd[1289]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyS1
Oct  5 12:37:36 localhost pppd[1289]: Remote message: Welcome!
Oct  5 12:37:36 localhost pppd[1289]: PAP authentication succeeded
Oct  5 12:37:40 localhost pppd[1289]: local  IP address 109.112.53.134
Oct  5 12:37:40 localhost pppd[1289]: remote IP address 109.112.235.129
Oct  5 12:37:40 localhost pppd[1289]: primary   DNS address 83.224.66.134
Oct  5 12:37:40 localhost pppd[1289]: secondary DNS address 83.224.65.134
```

#### References

- [PPP over GPRS link how to](http://www.acmesystems.it/ppp)
- [A 10-Minute Guide for Using PPP to Connect Linux to the Internet](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2109)
- [3G and GPRS modems with pppd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/3G_and_GPRS_modems_with_pppd)

Comment: Well, I don't, see **edit 2** for my ppp config above